# Communication Protocol for Transmitter Module

Tags: arduino, embedded, communication, i2c, spi

I am trying to figure out the communication protocol of the transmitter chip found inside an RC remote (FS-GT2B). Originally, I thought it was I2C but after some research it seems less likely because it is lacking some characteristic lines. The silkscreen says "SCK", "SCS" and "SDIO". Here's a picture of the chip's pinouts: [image]. Can anyone offer some pointers as to what the communication protocol of this guy is?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question so it's off topic.. When you've identified the chip and have questions about the code required to drive it come back.

Comment: @MikeW - untrue, apart from 5 minutes with a soldering iron to connect a dirt cheap logic analyzer, this is *entirely* a task of programming data manipulation.  One must analyze captured data, decode and understand it (presumably with the help of custom decoder programs or scripts), and then (presumably) replicate it with one's own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pins correspond to clock (SCK), chip select (SCS), and data input output (SDIO). You need to toggle the SCK pin in the appropriate way as you change or read the data on the SDIO pin. the SCS pin is likely for data direction (read or write).

There is no easy way to determine the protocol from a black box. Instead, you need to remove the RF shielding case to see the chip. A soldering iron and a solder sucker will do the job. Be careful not to overheat the circuit inside.

Use the number on chip to determine what kind of chip it is, then find the datasheet by searching the internet.

Once you have all that and write some code, this is appropriate place to ask questions about it.

Comment: No, you **do not** need to remove the shielding, and doing so **will not** reveal the protocol in most cases, but merely the chipset.  The standard approach to RC toys is to connect a CYC68013-based USB logic analyzer to capture data going into and out of the "black box".  This is then compared to the register information for various chips in common use to determine the chipset (or mutually compatible family).  Next, the captured payload data is analyzed to determine how various controls are encoded.

Comment: Hmm okay. Thanks for that! Is there a good source for getting a list of various chips in common use?

Comment: Also- does the USB logic analyzer have to be strictly CYC68013 based? or is something like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8938) okay?